# Convert to a urllib.request to an integer

Tags: python, int, urllib

Am I able to convert the value `us_price` into an integer after the following:

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen ("http://au.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AUDUSD=X")
text = page.read().decode("utf8")

where1 = text.find('yfs_l10_audusd=x">')

start_of_us_price = where1 + 18
end_of_us_price = start_of_us_price + 6

us_price = text[start_of_us_price:end_of_us_price]
```

I have tried `usp = int(us_price)` to no avail

Comment: what's the output of `print(type(us_price))` and `print(us_price)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use `float(us_price)`, but if you want int then `int(float(us_price))`.